# Array to string conversion in CodeIgniter while resizing

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter

I am trying to **create thumbnails**  for all my images inside a **directory**.
In my Controller I retrieve all the files from my directory like this.

```
$this->load->model('Home_model');

$this->load->helper('directory');

$dir = '../Mistletoe/Public/img/pics';

$AllImages = directory_map($dir);

$this->Home_model->resize($AllImages);
```

Then in my model I declared a path where the images are. 
In my Resize function, I join my Path with the filename.
But then I get The error:

*A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED*

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: models/home_model.php

Line Number: 21

```
<?php
class Home_model extends CI_Model
{

var $images_path;
var $images_path_thumbs;
function Home_model()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->images_path = base_url() . 'public/img/pics/';
    $this->images_path_thumbs = base_url() . 'public/img/pics/thumbs/';

}

function resize($imagesToProcess)
{
    foreach ($imagesToProcess as $val) 
    {
        $config = array
        (
            'source_image' => $this->images_path . $val,
            'new_image' => $this->images_path_thumbs,
            'maintain_ration' => true,
            'width' => 300,
            'heigth' => 206,
        );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

    $this->image_lib->resize();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: What is `$val`? Looks like it's probably an array.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($val);` inside the loop and post the result.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the doc here...

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/directory_helper.html

Looks like `$val` in your loop could be an array sometimes, representing a subdirectory (e.g., you have `thumbs` within `public/img/pics`). You may want to limit your `directory_map` to only 1 level:

```
$AllImages = directory_map($dir, 1);
```